# Codeigniter App with Symlink -Remove index.php from URL

Tags: codeigniter

I went through many resources here and elsewhere in net but couldnt seem to make it work.
I have codeigniter app in home directory. Sym link craeated in /var/www/html.
The below link works fine.

```
http://mydomain.net/dms/index.php/welcome
```

However without index.php ,I want the following link to work

```
http://mydomain.net/dms/welcome
```

---

Code igniter 2.1.1  directory:

```
dms
    application
    system
    index.php
    .htaccess
```

---

Config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = ""; 
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

---

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

---

Config file httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
Alias /dms/ "/var/www/html/dms/"
<Directory "/var/www/html/dms">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

---

sym links

```
ls -l /var/www/html
dms -> /home/user1/dms
```

---

.htaccess file  :

```
RewriteEngine On
# enable symbolic links
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php [L]
```

---

I tried keeping .htaccess file in CI folder folder /home/user1/dms and later in /var/www/html
Both didnt work.
I am getting error (in http error log)

```
"File does not exist: /var/www/html/dms/welcome"
```

Please help.

Comment: .htaccess file as given by Christian Giupponi below with correction I mentioned in comments worked.  AllowOverride All
at server level is not needed but at specific directory level it is must. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this .htaccess and it works for me, try:

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        # Make sure directory listing is disabled
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
        # disable the Apache MultiViews directive if it is enabled on the server. It plays havoc  with URL rewriting
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine on

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
        </IfModule>

    </IfModule>
```

Comment: I changed my .htaccess file in codeigniter app dir to what you have given above. Now I am getting 500 Internal Error. Log file shows - Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Any hints ?

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php/$1 [L] and RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]    worked. Thanks